# SQL query pivot INSIDE a case statement erroring

Tags: sql-server

The below code looks like it should work, but I get `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS`.  I think this is refering to the pivot of avg(testResults) on testrgstr_testname.

I have a table full of results for tests at various times of day.  I want to take all the results for sludge, dust and particle tests for a date range and average them on to a single row.

This has led to the use of a pivot.  The only issue is that the test names change depending on the time of year from JAMES, to FRANK to others names, which has led to the use of a case statement to allow for the different test names and hence the different columns after the pivot.

Apologies for any errors as this is stripped down version of my production code and I can't test it.

```
WITH
TestData as (
       SELECT TestName, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),result) as TestResult
  FROM TestReg
 WHERE  ResultDate BETWEEN @pFromDate AND @pToDate
   and (testrgstr_testname like '%Sludge%'
    or testrgstr_testname like '%Dust%'
    or testrgstr_testname like '%Particle%')
)

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @pCampType = 'JAMES' THEN
        (
            SELECT [JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AT] as s_at, [JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AO] as s_ao,
                   [JDTD JAMES Dust AT] as d_at, [JDTD JAMES Dust AO)] as d_ao,
                   [JDTD JAMES Particle_AT] as p_at, [JDTD JAMES Particle_AO] p_ao 
            FROM TestData 
            PIVOT 
            ( 
                avg(TestResult) 
                FOR testrgstr_testname 
                IN ([JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AT],[JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AO], 
                    [JDTD JAMES Dust AT, [JDTD JAMES Dust AO], 
                    [JDTD JAMES Particle_AT],[JDTD JAMES Particle_AO]) 
            ) as pvt
        )
    WHEN @pCampType = 'FRANK' THEN
        (
            SELECT [JDTD FRANK Cutting Sludge AT] as s_at, [JDTD JAMES FRANK Sludge AO] as s_ao,
                   [JDTD FRANK Dust AT] as d_at, [JDTD FRANK Dust AO)] as d_ao,
                   [JDTD FRANK Particle_AT] as p_at, [JDTD FRANK Particle_AO] as p_ao
            FROM TestData 
            PIVOT 
            ( 
                avg(TestResult) 
                FOR testrgstr_testname 
                IN ([JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AT],[JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AO], 
                    [JDTD JAMES Dust AT, [JDTD JAMES Dust AO], 
                    [JDTD JAMES Particle_AT],[JDTD JAMES Particle_AO]) 
            ) as pvt
        )
    ELSE
        (
            SELECT 'ERROR'
        )
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you should return a scalar from THEN:

```
        SELECT [JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AT] as s_at, [JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AO] as s_ao,
               [JDTD JAMES Dust AT] as d_at, [JDTD JAMES Dust AO)] as d_ao,
               [JDTD JAMES Particle_AT] as p_at, [JDTD JAMES Particle_AO] p_ao
        ...
```

returns a result set, not a single value.

You can either use IF statement and perform a statement for each of your case -  `@pCampType = 'JAMES'` / `@pCampType = 'FRANK'` or use a dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    WITH
    TestData as (
           SELECT TestName, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),result) as TestResult
      FROM TestReg
     WHERE  ResultDate BETWEEN @pFromDate AND @pToDate
       and (testrgstr_testname like ''%Sludge%''
        or testrgstr_testname like ''%Dust%''
        or testrgstr_testname like ''%Particle%'')
    )'

DECLARE @InnerSelectSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

IF (@pCampType = 'JAMES')
    @InnerSelectSQL = N'
            SELECT [JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AT] as s_at, [JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AO] as s_ao,
                   [JDTD JAMES Dust AT] as d_at, [JDTD JAMES Dust AO)] as d_ao,
                   [JDTD JAMES Particle_AT] as p_at, [JDTD JAMES Particle_AO] p_ao '
ELSE IF (@pCampType = 'FRANK')
    @InnerSelectSQL = N'
            SELECT [JDTD FRANK Cutting Sludge AT] as s_at, [JDTD JAMES FRANK Sludge AO] as s_ao,
                   [JDTD FRANK Dust AT] as d_at, [JDTD FRANK Dust AO)] as d_ao,
                   [JDTD FRANK Particle_AT] as p_at, [JDTD FRANK Particle_AO] as p_ao '

SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + InnerSelectSQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'
    FROM TestData 
            PIVOT 
            ( 
                avg(TestResult) 
                FOR testrgstr_testname 
                IN ([JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AT],[JDTD JAMES Cutting Sludge AO], 
                    [JDTD JAMES Dust AT, [JDTD JAMES Dust AO], 
                    [JDTD JAMES Particle_AT],[JDTD JAMES Particle_AO]) 
            ) as pvt'

Dynamic SQL is uglier, but you avoid repetition.
```

Comment: Is it just me or is the second use of James/Frank not taken account of in the PIVOT?  I'm better in PLSQL so happy to learn here.

Comment: That said.  THANKS.  I get where I'm going wrong, though the error doesn't seem to point to that to me.